# horizontally scrolling div and positioning of child elements

Tags: css

Not as simple as it may sound.

I have a horizontally scrolling div, the content within is dynamic and may change.

What I've managed to do so far is get it behaving properly in webkit, but try as I might, it won't work properly in either firefox, opera and probably IE.

The structure is pretty simple, a container, a relatively positioned parent and a ul with list items inside.

```
<div class="extra-holder">
    <div class="extra-holder-inner">
        <ul>        
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>               
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>  


.extra-holder {
    height: 160px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 41;

    line-height: 1;
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
    -o-transition-duration: .2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: .2s;
    transition-duration: .2s;
}

.extra-holder-inner {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.extra-holder ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.extra-holder ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    height: 140px;
    width: 300px;
    white-space:normal;
    border-left: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

The problem is, the list items seem to wrap, I need them all in a line that users can scroll along.

I made a jsfiddle so you can get a better idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/QFnVk/

in chrome - can scroll left/right
in firefox - list items display as many as the viewport width allows, then stack below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.extra-holder ul li` rule, try replacing `float: left;` with `display: inline-block;`

Here is your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QFnVk/2/) working in Firefox

Comment: That sort of works, the problem becomes, when there's actually content inside the list items, images, headers etc, they don't line up properly.

Comment: @andy give `vertical-align: top` to `li` elements. It will solve the problem :).

Comment: That has indeed fixed the problem, 1000 internets to both of you, good sirs.